# How to get the task_struct of a pid?

Tags: linux, c, monitoring, time

I would like to get the task_struct of a process by his PID because I need the timing fields for a monitoring application. Is that possible without creating a module ?
If not, is there a way to get the start time of the process, his execution time in user and kernel modes, his last execution ... etc

Answer (score 0):

The task_struct is not directly exposed, but a lot is available in /proc/**PID**, which is documented in [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). In particular /proc/**PID**/stat has a number of fields which looks like this.

```
663969 (bash) S 255279 663969 663969 34836 721047 4194304 1103 125311 1 2396 1 2 2385 4333 20 0 1 0 152947991 9584640 1123 18446744073709551615 94761163685888 94761164450717 140730124580704 0 0 0 65536 3686404 1266761467 0 0 0 17 0 0 0 5 0 0 94761164686000 94761164733764 94761175252992 140730124584237 140730124584243 140730124584243 140730124586990 0
```

The 1-based fields include the PID 663969 (field 1), the PPID 255279 (field 4), the execution time in user space 1 (field 14) and system space 2 (field 15), and the start time 152947991 (field 22 in clock ticks). Not clear what `last execution` means.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I need a higher resolution of the execution time and the field in /proc/PID/stat is not enough.
By last execution l meant the time when the process left the cpu.